# Recycler view in fragment doesn't appear after close and reopen app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with Recycler view. it does not appear when i close and reopen the application.

**1)** Im using fragments, when i add an item to the recycler it appears normally:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y8X6.png

**2)** When I close the app and then reopen it, the image doesn't load.

[image]

**onCreateView** of my fragment:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        loadRecycler();
        return v;
    }
```

**loadRecycler() method:**

```
private void loadRecycler() {
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Animales");
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Animal animal = snap.getValue(Animal.class);
                        mlist.add(new AnimalAdapterData(animal.getNombre(),animal.getImageURL()));
                    }
                }
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**onViewCreated method:**

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(),mlist);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

**HomeAdapter class:**

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<AnimalAdapterData> mData;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<AnimalAdapterData> mData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        AnimalAdapterData currentItem = mData.get(position);
        String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageURL();
        String title = currentItem.getNombre();
        holder.mTextView.setText(title);
       Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView mImageView;
        TextView mTextView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

I think that im using correctly the onCreateView and onViewCreated method, but idk whats going on with this.

Comment: Could you also post the code for HomeAdapter?

Comment: Yes, i edited it there

Comment: Did you check if the problem is with only image or entire item? Try adding a black colour to text and verify if it is displayed on second attempt?

Comment: @rajanks I tried what you said, and yes, the problem is only with the image. The text appears correctly

Comment: The problem was in the activity that called this fragment where the recycler is shown, solved. Thank you for answer